# ceil function in C

Tags: c, casting, int, ceil

- I think `ceil()` function should have given `2.000000` instead of `1.000000` when I write :

```c
int main() {

    printf( "%f", ceil(5/3) );

    return 0;
}
```

and `floor()` function gives `1.000000` as expected. I don't understand why ceil is giving `1.000000`.

- The snippet below prints 0 and I don't know why :

```c
int main() {
    printf("%d", ceil(5.0/3));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second snippet has undefined behaviour, since `ceil()` returns `double`.  The `%d` format tells `printf()` to ASSUME the corresponding argument is an `int` and, if anything other than `int` (i.e. `double` in this case) gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: `5/3` is `1` as that is integer division.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `ceil` is `double ceil(double x);`.

`printf( "%f", ceil((double)5/3) );` should work as you are expecting. `5/3` is integer division. The `ceil` function receives `1` as a result of the integer division (as the digits after the decimal are discarded) and can do very little from there.

Casting atleast one of the operands of the `/` operator to `double` will result in a floating point division and the digits after the decimal will be preserved.

You need to pass a fractional number to `ceil` for it to do what you want.

In the comments below, Chux provides an alternative method of doing this.

Comment: Coercing a floating point division can be done with more gently with `1.0*` as in `1.0*a/b` than a cast.  A good compiler with emit efficient code either way.  Casts such a `(float)` can lose information as code may later change `a,b` from `int` to `double` and then the cast in an unedited `(float)a/b` is not only not needed, it tosses away precision and range and can result in a wrong quotient.